# Chrome console accessing DOM

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console

When i put in my chrome console something like:

```
document.getElementById('scroller')
```

I get back something like:

```
<div class="blah" id="scroller>...</div>
```

But if i pause a script and throw in a watch by the same expression I'll get javascript object, how do I get the javascript object in the regular console like:

```
document.getElementById('scroller'): div#scroller.multipleFiles
   accessKey: ""
   align: ""
   attributes : NamedNodeMap
   baseURI : "http://localhost:3000/cards.html#card-text-download-cycler"
   childElementCount: 12
   childNodes: NodeList[25]
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.dir(document.getElementById('scroller'))
```